# Convert String to Date/Time in Report Builder query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column ENTRY_MONTH with dates in it as a string like 11/2017.

I'm trying to convert the column to datetime, preferably the last day of each month, so in the example above would be  11-30-2017.

I've tried

```
CONVERT(datetime, ENTRY_MONTH, 110)
```

to no avail. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
DECLARE @MyDate varchar(16) = '11/2017'
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(m,1,CONVERT(datetime, '1/' + @MyDate, 103)))
```

This uses a European format where the day comes first. Add a month on then take a day off takes you to the end of the month.

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(datetime,right(entrymonth,4) + left(entrymonth,2) + '01')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this.

```
Declare @strDate varchar(10) = '11/2017'

-- concatenate '01/' to get the first date of the month.
--  (it is needed to make a proper date, 
-- and not necessary to make it the first date, it can be '17/' as well 
Select '01/' + @strDate
Select Convert(DateTime,'01/' + @strDate, 103)
-- the EOMONTH can be used here
Select EOMONTH(Convert(DateTime,'01/' + @strDate, 103))
```

in your case:

```
 EOMONTH(Convert(DateTime,'01/' + ENTRY_MONTH, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go step by step converting and formatting, you can do it like this (intermediate results shown in the result, too):

```sql
DECLARE @entryMonth VARCHAR(7) = '11/2017';

SELECT
    @entryMonth AS "entry month",
    FORMAT( -- create a date from the parts you have in the varchar and a 1 for the day
        DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(@entryMonth, 4), LEFT(@entryMonth, 2), 1),
        'MM-dd-yyyy'    -- and format it the way you want
    ) AS "First of month",
    FORMAT(
        DATEADD(MONTH,
                1,  -- add a month in order to get the first of next month
                FORMAT(
                    DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(@entryMonth, 4), LEFT(@entryMonth, 2), 1),
                    'MM-dd-yyyy')
        ),
        'MM-dd-yyyy'
    ) AS "First day next month",
    FORMAT(
        DATEADD(DAY,
                -1, -- subtract a day from the first of next month
                DATEADD(MONTH, 1, FORMAT(
                                    DATEFROMPARTS(RIGHT(@entryMonth, 4), LEFT(@entryMonth, 2), 1),
                                    'MM-dd-yyyy'))
                ),
        'MM-dd-yyyy'
    ) AS "Last day entry month"
```

```
entry month     First of month  First day next month    Last day entry month
    11/2017         11-01-2017            12-01-2017              11-30-2017
```